# Powershell passing variables to a job

Tags: windows, variables, powershell, csv, jobs

```
Function start
{
$BackupList = Import-Csv C:\file.csv -Delimiter ";"
    ForEach($computer in $BackupList) 
    {
        $arrayBackup = ($computer.Backup).split(".")
        $backupdate = Get-Date -Day $arrayBackup[0] -Month $arrayBackup[1] -Year $arrayBackup[2]
        $datetoday = Get-Date -format d
        $countingday = (get-date $datetoday).AddMonths(-3)
            if ($Zahl -eq 1) 
            {
                if ($backupdate -le $countingday) 
                {
                $global:client = $computer.computername
                $global:mac = $computer.MAC
                $global:Name = $computer.device
                $global:lastsaved = [int]$computer.lastsavetime
                    if ($computer.computername -match $Client) 
                    {
                                        {
                                $computer.Backup = $datetoday
                                if ($lastsaved -ne 4) 
                                {
                                        $lastsaved++
                                } 
                                else 
                                {
                                    $lastsaved = 1
                                }
                                    if ($lastsaved -eq 1) 
                                    {
                                        $global:savingplace = "\\Savingplace1"
                                    }
                                    elseif ($lastsaved -eq 2) 
                                    {
                                        $global:savingplace = "\\Savingplace2"
                                    }
                                    elseif ($lastsaved -eq 3) 
                                    {
                                        $global:savingplace = "\\Savingplace3"
                                    }
                                    elseif ($lastsaved -eq 4) 
                                    {
                                        $global:savingplace = "\\Savingplace4"
                                    }
                                $computer.lastsavetime = $lastsaved
                            }   
                        }
                        Start-Job -InitializationScript $functions -ScriptBlock {NASLOGIN} -argumentlist $_ | Receive-Job
                    }
    }   
}
}
```

I am reading some information out of a csv-file.
i want to pass some of this information read to a job.
in the job im doing quiet a lot of function calls and operations using this variables.
but at the moment there is no variable passed to the job.
how can i fix this?

Comment: maybe i'm a little bit retarded but how can i pass all variables from the line of csv-file to my job?

Comment: how do you know there is no variable passed? we would need to see the contents of your scripblock. $_ gets passed but you probably dont use it right

Comment: in  my scriptblock there are a lot of functions. One of them is for example naslogin. in this function there is checked which value lastsaved has, depending on the value it sets some other variables. after setting them there is called another function doing a ping on the computer defined in $client. and so on. i need the variables for the whole scriptblock and i'm using them in many different functions.

Comment: then show us how you try to access the variable in the scripblock, otherwise its just guessing

Comment: Function NASLogin {
 if ($lastsaved -eq 1) { 
  $global:login = "login" 
  $global:pswd = "password"
 } 
 ELSEIF ($lastsaved -eq 2) { 
  $global:login = "login" 
  $global:pswd = "password"
 } 
 ELSEIF ($lastsaved -eq 3) { 
  $global:login = "login" 
  $global:pswd = "password"
 } 
 ELSEIF ($lastsaved -eq 4) { 
  $global:login = "login" 
  $global:pswd = "password"
 }
    CheckSystemOn
}
Function CheckSystemOn{
 IF (ClientPing) {
  PlattformCheck
 } ELSE {
  C:\wol.exe $mac
  Waitfors
 }
}
Function ClientPing{
test-connection $client -quiet -Count 1
}
sorry don't know how to get it formatted

Comment: you arent even using the variable you pass, i suggest you read some documentation (maybe start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847893.aspx) then fix your code and come back if you really have a problem (other then "i dont know how this works")

Comment: my script looks like 
$functions = { 
functions shown above
}
so i guess this is what you wanted me to do!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Start-Job -ScriptBlock {NASLOGIN $args[0]$args[1]$args[2]$args[3]$args[4]} -argumentlist $var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5 -InitializationScript $functions
            }
        }
    }
    $functions = 
    { 
        Function NASLogin 
        {
            $var1 = $args[0]
            $var2 = $args[1]
            $var3 = $args[2]
            $var4 = $args[3]
            $var5 = $args[4]`

Have done it like this and it works.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `$_` to the ArgumentList parameter but I don't see anywhere in where you code where there is a pipeline active - hence $_ is not defined.  To pass variables to the job, specify valid variables in the ArgumentList e.g.:

```
$foo = 'foo'
$bar = 'bar'
Start-Job {param($a, $b) "a is $a, b is $b"} -Arg $foo,$bar | Receive-Job -Wait
```

Comment: so, i have to do it like that: Start-Job -InitializationScript $functions -ScriptBlock {NASLOGIN} -argumentlist $client,$mac,$name,$lastsaved,$savingplace | Receive-Job ? but this also doesnt work.

Comment: What is NASLOGIN?  Is that defined in the scriptblock $functions?  I would start simple and work out from there to see what the problem is.  Also if you pipe to Receive-Job without using -Wait, Receive-Job will return whatever output it sees (probably none) and complete before your job has had chance to do much.